# Fluid-dynamics question: proper term

Tags: fluid-mechanics, terminology

I am looking for the term used to describe a situation I've encountered. I'll use a standard hydraulic cartridge that you'd use to keep a door shut as an example, except this one can be locked out with a rotary valve. How would you refer to the valve being pushed open by pressure or load? If under pressure, the valve is unable to close until pressure is relieved. Is there a term for this? I thought it may have been "Jetting", but that doesn't exactly describe this situation.

Answer (score 1):

pressure relief valve - limits or controls the pressure to the set limit.

At least based on your description...